# Database schema and query to accumualte total amount of days for each "category" of an animal over a period of time

Tags: postgresql, database-design, relational-database, database-schema, supabase

I am trying to design a PostgreSQL database using Supabase to store information about animals and their categoriee, like age and gender, which will be used to define the category.

For example: The category of a young male horse would be a colt while a young female horse would be a filly. For adult horses the categories would be different and could be influenced by other factors such as castration state etc.

I need a database to query a selected period of time and get back the total amount of days of each category. So if for the time frame of 40 days there were 5 colts and 3 fillies in the database, the result of the query would be

```
Colts 5 * 40 = 200 
Fillies 3 * 40 = 120
```

My first attempt used an SQLite database and native Android development. I had a table for the `animals` and one for the `transfers` between categories. The transfers table had the initial category of the animal and the new category as well as what type of transfer it was (birth, death, purchase, sale etc.).

The query first gets the quantity of animals in each category at the start date, then alter the quantities based on the transfers table for following days and add those numbers up. Apart from getting the data out of the database using simple select statements, everything was done using Kotlin and it took a noticeable amount of time if done on an older device or emulator, and since I plan to use Supabase I am trying to come up with a solution which would do all the computing on the back end.

This has three tables. One is for `animals`, which would only store age, gender and some other relevant information such as castration state etc. A second stores the `categories` with some information about them (name, description, etc..) and the third stores the information about the `transfers` between the categories. I store the id of the animal, the category, the date on which it was transferred to this category all as non-nullable values and the date on which it was transferred out of this category as a nullable value.

[image: database schema]

I don't know how to query to get the quantities for each category over a period of time. My idea is to find the difference between start_date and end_date (substitute end_date with selected end_date if it is null) in days and add these numbers up for each category.

What is good and bad about that solution?

How could I structure the SQL statement?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) An ERD is an image of DDL--text.

Comment: Clearly, when pinned down & clearly expressed parts of your goal will be faqs. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Comment: Ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question.

Comment: Sometimes when i see editing like philipxy's on the original post, I wish we could also upvote on edits....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get what you want just by looking at the transfers table. Just count the days between start and enddate, limited by the input_start_date and input_end_date you give as parameters, and sum them together grouped by the category_id

```
SELECT category_id,
       Sum(Max(( Min(end_date, input_end_date) -
                 Max(start_date, input_start_date) ), 0
           ))
FROM   transfers
GROUP  BY category_id
```

Comment: np, In modelling a sollution, first think carefully about what you need. In this case number of cases per category, per timesperiod. What the categories mean, and which animals it connects to is for that question not of importance. So you can igore those tables. All needed info (category_id and dates) are in the same table. Then it becomes a much easier problem on a single table.